# Construct a diffeomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $\Gamma$ which maps to the parabola of the equation $y = x^2$.

Tags: analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and 
$$\Gamma = \left \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y=f(x) \right \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$$ its function graph.

Construct a diffeomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$,  which maps $\Gamma$ to the parabola with the equation $y = x^2$.

This was one of my exam questions and I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\phi(x, y) = (x, x^2 + y-f(x)).
$$

I'm assuming you meant to say "which maps $\Gamma$ to the parabola with equation $y = x^2$.